# VLC - use web-plugin to stream local tv or video input on a encore enutv-4

Tags: html, vlc, tv-tuner, tuner

This is my first post. I need to stream from a tv-tuner on my web-app. I am trying to configure the tv tuner and I have got to far. I can't find (or understand) in the official documentation how pass parameters to the web-plugin. Even if I could, I don't know how to make it pick the video (composite, rca, IDK) by default.

Any help you can offer me, will be really appreciated. Thanks in advance!

PS1: I can hear alternatives to VLC, but it is what have "worked" so far, by passing the

`target="dshow://"`

option in the html tag

edit0: I read in the documentation[0] that: " channel=0 is the number of the channel (usually 0 is for tuner, 1 for composite and 2 for svideo),
 ", but I don't know how to pass this to the web-plugin.

[0]https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Streaming_HowTo/Stream_from_Encoding_Cards_and_Other_Capture_Devices/#Stream_with_VLC_2

edit1: my code so far, have tried to  pass parameters in the target option, but with no luck :(

`<embed target="dshow://" width="840" height="680" id="vlc" />`

Comment: Show what you have tried so far. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: well, basically this `<embed target="dshow://" width="840" height="680" id="vlc" />`` , I guess I have to pass some parameters, but don't really know how, in the wiki I just see Width and stuffs like that

Comment: Is not an answer, but if you run the command to launch the vlc on a CMD, the web-plugin will take those parameters, now all I need to know is how do I pass those parameters to the web-plugin directly.